# Navigation bar disappear on click

Tags: javascript, css, nav

I have this navigation menu with a hamburger icon as well, I used a JS function to make the list disappear when the hamburger icon is clicked. However, I would like to trigger an animation on the burger icon as well as hide the list when clicked.

Should I create another function, or just use the first one for both actions.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    wrapper.classList.remove("wrapper");
    wrapper.classList.add("close");
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.add("wrapper");
    wrapper.classList.remove("close");
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.burger::before {
  content: "";
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.burger::after {
  content: "";
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.close .navlist {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="burger">Burger</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navlist">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"how would I trigger an animation on the burger icon as well as hide the list on click"* - the list already hides when you click the burger, and the way you would create the animation depends on what the animation is. Some possible ways are to toggle a css class on the burger-icon button, or messing with the CSS properties of said button.

Comment: I know about the hiding list part, the animation is basically just a function that would add a new class to the burger, which then rotates the burger lines in a specific matter, since that should be happening on click as well, should I just use the function above for the animation as well?

Comment: Second part of your question is unclear

Comment: I have a function, the function closes the list on click, if I wanted to add new classes to the burger div on click( which would then be styled on CSS), should I create an entirely new function OR should I just use the same function that closes the list.

Comment: @drinos, well it depends. If the process of adding classes is complicated and long and requires logic checks, I would say create a new function. Otherwise I would just use the function above.